# Lambda function in Java skips elements

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a row which I need to parse which looks like:

`@UNIT,a,b,c,,,,d,e,,,`

and I expect Java to store the following values in a list:

```
[0] => a
[1] => b
[2] => c
[3] => null
[4] => null
[5] => null
[6] => d
[7] => e
[8] => null
[9] => null
[10] => null
```

I want to comma separate the values by comma and replace empty values with `null`.

I archive most of the part with the following code:

```
metaObject.unit = Arrays.stream(line
        .split(","))
        .skip(line.startsWith("@UNIT,") ? 1 : 0)
        .map(String::trim)
        .map(s -> " ".equals(s) || "".equals(s) || "_".equals(s)? null : s)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Where `metaObject.unit` is defined as `List<String> unit = new ArrayList<String>();`

The problem is that Java ignores the empty elements which occure after the last non-empty element. The output I get in the given case is:

```
[0] => a
[1] => b
[2] => c
[3] => null
[4] => null
[5] => null
[6] => d
[7] => e
```

I do not understand why Java does not threat the empty elements as before. Is there any trick to get this fixed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem actually comes from `line.split(",")`.

By default, quoting the Javadoc of [`split(regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-):

> Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

So the result of this call is `[@UNIT, a, b, c, , , , d, e]`.

What you want is to include the trailing empty strings, so you need to call `line.split(",", -1)` (note the negative second parameter). Quoting the Javadoc of [`split(regex, limit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-), about the `limit` parameter:

> If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length.

Corrected code:

```
metaObject.unit = Arrays.stream(line
    .split(",", -1))
    .skip(line.startsWith("@UNIT,") ? 1 : 0)
    .map(String::trim)
    .map(s -> s.isEmpty() || "_".equals(s) ? null : s)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(Note that I removed the call to `" ".equals(s)` since if that were the case, the preceding call to `trim` would have made that String an empty String, and, as Holger points out in his comment, I replaced `"".equals(s)` with the cleaner `s.isEmpty()`).

Comment: And then you can replace `"".equals(s)` with `s.isEmpty()` which is much cleaner, imho.

Comment: @Holger, for me the much cleaner would be to create a separate method like `boolean isEmptyEntry(String s) { return s.isEmpty() || s.equals(" ") || s.equals("_"); }`, so it can be separately supported, tested and reused. Btw in current code `s.equals(" ")` is never true as happens after `trim`.

Comment: @Drudge, if your IDE has auto-completion the second parameter should show up in the suggested results whenever you type `.spl␣`. Actually studying the docs is half the battle ;)

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: it has already been addressed in the answer that the string can never be `" "`. I’m not sure whether `s.isEmpty() || s.equals("_")` exceeds the threshold to deserve a testable method on its own. Btw., you could also write `s.matches("_?")` to test everything with one call, however, it might feel like bearing some overhead…